# htaccess RewriteRules 2 subfolders to 2 separate files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect 2 separate virtual directories to files using rewriterules in htaccess

The **first virtual** directory is `admin` and should redirect to `admin.php`

`http://dev.int/shop/admin` > `http://dev.int/shop/admin.php/`

`http://dev.int/shop/admin/` > `http://dev.int/shop/admin.php/`

`http://dev.int/shop/admin/products` > `http://dev.int/shop/admin.php/products`

`http://dev.int/shop/admin/products/add` > `http://dev.int/shop/admin.php/products/add`

The **second virtual** directory is anything else and should redirect to `index.php`

`http://dev.int/shop/anything` > `http://dev.int/shop/index.php/anything`

`http://dev.int/shop/anything/else` > `http://dev.int/shop/index.php/anything/else`

There is also some other criteria in that the directories `assets` and `_test` and the files `robots.txt` and `sitemap.xml` should not be redirected

This is what I have so far but it's not working :(

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(assets|_test)
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|admin\.php|robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml)
RewriteRule ^admin/?(.*)$ /shop/admin.php/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(?:admin)/?(.*)$ /shop/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Basically the string `admin` should be replaced with `admin.php` keeping the same URL structure and the same applies to string `index`. Is that right?

Comment: @faa `admin` yes, but anything else except `assets`, `_test`, `robots.txt` and `sitemap.xml` should go to `index.php`

Comment: Not completely clear yet. To `index.php,` where? Here: `http://dev.int/shop/index.php/anything` in your question is at `/shop` directory, while here: `/itmanx/shop/draytek/index.php/$1` in your rule is at `draytek` directory. Please update your question with the missing  information.

Comment: @faa - sorry, have corrected the htaccess file

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# "admin" string is present
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(assets|_test|robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml)  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/shop/admin(.*)?/? [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !admin\.php          [NC]
RewriteRule .              shop/admin.php%1     [R=301,L]

# "admin" string is NOT present
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(assets|_test|robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml|admin)  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/shop(.*)?/?       [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php          [NC]
RewriteRule .              shop/index.php%1     [R=301,L]
```

When `admin` string is present after the `/shop/` folder, redirects permanently:

`http://dev.int/shop/admin/any/number/of/folders`  with or without trailing slash.

To:

`http://dev.int/shop/admin.php/any/number/of/folders`

Replacing `admin` with `admin.php` in the path stream without any other modification.

---

When `admin` string is NOT present at all, redirects permanently:

`http://dev.int/shop/any/number/of/folders`  with or without trailing slash.

To:

`http://dev.int/shop/index.php/any/number/of/folders`

Inserting `index.php` after the `/shop/` folder in the path stream without any other modification.

---

None of the above rules is applied when the incoming URL contains:

`assets`, `_test`, `robots.txt` or `sitemap.xml` in the path stream.

For silent mapping, remove `R=301` from `[R=301,L]`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @faa for his support and guidance.  Below is the working answer.

```
RewriteEngine On

# backend
RewriteCond $1 !^(\.php)  [NC]
RewriteRule ^admin(.*)$ /itmanx/shop/draytek/admin.php$1 [R=301,L]

# frontend
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|admin|assets|__test|robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml)  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /itmanx/shop/draytek/index.php/$1 [R=301,L]
```